# step by step how to install office 2007 into a 32bit wine prefix

Tags: wine, 64-bit

i am very new to Ubuntu, and after exploring the different flavors i have chosen Xubuntu 14.04 lst. I am trying to install office 2007 with wine, but ran into the known bugs of running 32bit applications within 64bit wine.

I have read the how to's on creating a 32bit wine prefix, but i haven't found any thing on how to actually preform the install into this newly created 32bit prefix.

Could you provide a step by step on how to preform this office 2007 install into a 32bit prefix?

i am comfortable using the terminal, i simply do not have enough experience using linux yet.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

1. Open a terminal,

   Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Run it:

   `$ sudo -i`

   `# apt-get update`

   `# apt-get install wine winetricks`

   `# exit`

   `$ sh winetricks msxml3 dotnet20 gdiplus riched20 riched30 vcrun2005sp1`
3. Enter Wine Configuration

   `Click Libraries tab`

   `Add riched20`

   `Select it and click edit.`

   `Choose built in then native.`
4. Go to Microsoft Office 2007 and open setup.exe.
5. If launching an application seems to freeze on the splash screen, try pres the enter key.

Answer (score 1):

Try PlayOnLinux. It does all the housekeeping and works super well for Office. I as running 2007, but am now running 2010 under 64-bit Wine.

Comment: Ok i have installed PlayOnLinux and i no longer have the 32bit error using wine, however i have a file association error. i have created a file association in the file properties with the following code:playonlinux --run "Microsoft Word 2007" '"z:%f"'  but when i right click on a .doc file word opens with an error [link]http://www.rlfleming.com/dls/playonlinux-error.png and when i click ok word opens a blank document.

Answer (score 0):

https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=28033#p108175
It works for me. Word, Excel and PowerPoint works.